# SQL Server Default field value

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server, I have a field which is a bit. I need to default it to 0 on insert of a new record. I thought there was a way for SQL Server to automatically create a constraint without writing code. I thought there was a way to right click on the field and go to properties. I tried but do not see how to default a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio: Select the table from the tree, context menu, design table, select the field, in the properties grid at the bottom type a zero (0) in the Default row, save.